# Get all node descendants in a tree

Tags: python, performance, tree, graph, pandas

I have a CSV holding a "flat" table of a tree's edges (NOT binary, but a node cannot have two parents), ~1M edges:

```
node_id parent_id
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       2
...
```

The nodes are sorted in a way that a `parent_id` must always come before any of its children, so a `parent_id` will always be lower than `node_id`.

I wish, for each node_id, to get the set of all ancestor nodes (including itself, propagated until root which is node 0 here), and a set of all descendant nodes (including itself, propagated until leaves), and speed is crucial.

Currently what I do at high level:

1. Read the CSV in pandas, call it `nodes_df`
2. Iterate once through `nodes_df` to get `node_ancestors`, a `{node_id: set(ancestors)}` dict adding for each node's ancestors itself and its parent's ancestors (which I know I have seen all by then)
3. Iterate through `nodes_df` again *in reverse order* to get `node_descendants`, a `{node_id: set(ancestors)}` dict adding for each node's descendants itself and its child's descendants (which I know I have seen all by then)

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# phase 1
nodes_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

# phase 2
node_ancestors = defaultdict(set)
node_ancestors[0] = set([0])
for id, ndata in nodes_df1.iterrows():
    node_ancestors[ndata['node_id']].add(ndata['node_id'])
    node_ancestors[ndata['node_id']].update(node_ancestors[ndata['parent_id']])

# phase 3
node_descendants = defaultdict(set)
node_descendants[0] = set([0])
for id, ndata in nodes_df1[::-1].iterrows():
    node_descendants[ndata['node_id']].add(ndata['node_id'])
    node_descendants[ndata['parent_id']].\
      update(node_descendants[ndata['node_id']])
```

So, this takes dozens of seconds on my laptop, which is ages for my application. How do I improve?

Plausible directions:

1. Can I use pandas better? Can I get `node_ancestors` and/or `node_descendants` by some clever join which is out of my league?
2. Can I use a python graph library like `Networkx` or `igraph` (which in my experience is faster on large graphs)? E.g. in both libraries I have a `get_all_shortest_paths` methods, which returns something like a `{node_id: dist}` dictionary, from which I could select the keys, but... I need this for every node, so again a long long loop
3. Parallelizing - no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

## `id`

you shadow the builtin `id` with this name as variable

## itertuples

a way to improve performance is using `itertuples` to iterate over the `DataFrame`: `for _, node, parent in df.itertuples():`

## iterations

You can do this in 1 iteration over the input with a nested loop over the ancestors:

```
node_ancestors = defaultdict(set)
node_ancestors[0] = set([0])
node_descendants = defaultdict(set)
node_descendants[0] = set([0])
for _, node, parent in df.itertuples():
    node_ancestors[node].add(node)
    node_ancestors[node].update(node_ancestors[parent])

    for ancestor in node_ancestors[node]:
        node_descendants[ancestor].add(node)
```

Depending on how nested the tree is, this will be faster or slower than iterating over the whole input twice. You'll need to test it on your dataset.

## global vs local

another speedup might be achieved by doing this in a function instead of the global namespace ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12590058/1562285))

```
def parse_tree(df):
    node_ancestors = defaultdict(set)
    node_ancestors[0] = set([0])
    node_descendants = defaultdict(set)
    node_descendants[0] = set([0])
    for _, node, parent in df.itertuples():
        node_ancestors[node].add(node)
        node_ancestors[node].update(node_ancestors[parent])

        for ancestor in node_ancestors[node]:
            node_descendants[ancestor].add(node)

    return node_ancestors, node_descendants
```

Comment: Not `parents[node] = parent` isn't necessary.